# Sending email to myself with OS X "Mail" does not work, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: macos, email, google-workspace

I am using Google Apps to host my own domain, and uses IMAP to fetch the mail to OS X Mail program.

It is working well in every aspect except one. I can not send emails to myself with OS X Mail. They never return. I'm not getting anything bounced or any error messages.

- Sending to any other email address works.
- Sending from my phone works.
- Sending from my Windows computer works.
- Sending to myself from another (identically configured, also hosted through google apps) email account within OS X Mail works.

I'm scratching my head, I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this.

I am often sending mail to myself as a way to take notes, but also to put files onto the IMAP-server.

The servers I'm using are `imap.gmail.com` and `smtp.gmail.com` port 993 SSL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem I read about [on the Risks digest](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/Risks/26.57.html#subj10.2) where gmail considers incoming messages duplicates (and hence discards them) if they match messages already in the account, *including* the accounts's sent mail folder (i.e. the message was sent from the same account).  Maybe OS X Mail is putting the outgoing messages in sent messages, but the other methods you tried don't do this?

Comment: You are right, that is part of the problem. I found out that I logged in to my SMTP-server with the other accounts user name (OS X Mail stores the SMTP-server with it's credentials and reuses them if another account selects that server). Changing the SMTP-login fixed it. However, now my emails to the other email address it automatically sent to that email address "sent mail"-box. Funny! However, I don't mind that.